# While loop doesn't initialize

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, ubuntu-16.04, wchar-t

I've got a problem. Here is a function that processes the width of a wide-string. My program is entering an infinite loop after **BREAKPOINT 1**. What's wrong with my loop?

```
static void ft_wstr_width(void)
{
    wchar_t *temp;
    size_t  delta;
    size_t  len;
    size_t  i;
    wint_t  wc;

    len = ft_wstrlen(g_ws);
    delta = (size_t)g_fmt.width - ft_wstrsize(g_ws);
    printf("(%d %zd)\n", g_fmt.width, ft_wstrsize(g_ws));
    temp = (wchar_t *)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * (len + delta + 1));
    temp[len + delta] = L'\0';
    if (g_fmt.flags[0])
    {
        wc = (QWSZ ? L'0' : L' ');
        i = 0;
        while (i < delta);
        {
            temp[i] = wc;
            ++i;
        }
        ft_wcopy(temp, g_ws, delta, len);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("[bp0]"); getchar(); // BREAKPOINT 0
        ft_wcopy(temp, g_ws, 0, len);
        i = len;
        printf("[bp1]"); getchar(); // BREAKPOINT 1
        while (i < len + delta);
        {
            printf("[bp2]"); getchar(); // BREAKPOINT 2
            temp[i] = L' ';
            ++i;
        }
    }
    printf("[bp3]"); getchar(); // BREAKPOINT 3
    free(g_ws);
    g_ws = temp;
}
```

-----UBUNTU TERMINAL OUTPUT-----

```
stanislav:gh_ft_printf >>: ./a.out                                          
(15 3)
[bp0]
[bp1]         No reaction here (program keeps running) and
^C    <----   I have to kill the process with Ctrl+C
```

Comment: A debugger would show you that you're stuck at `while (i < len + delta);` because of the extra semicolon. Turning on compiler warnings would probably also have told you that.

Comment: @Raymond - It sounds like he was using a debugger. I'm guessing he did not know how to interpret the results he saw under the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while (i < len + delta)**;**

Semi-colon.

Comment: ow.... right)
thanks!